# Utilizar sum com Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT P.ID
      ,P.NR_CRACHA     CRACHA
      ,P.NM_CLIENTE     NOME
      ,E.DS_EMPRESA    EMPRESA
      ,SUM( R.VL_PRECO ) VALOR
 FROM registro R
      JOIN pessoa   P
      JOIN empresa E
      WHERE P.CD_PESSOA  = R.CD_PESSOA
  AND E.CD_EMPRESA = P.CD_EMPRESA   
  AND (P.NM_PESSOA LIKE :pessoa OR P.NR_CRACHA LIKE :cracha)
  AND R.SN_PAGO = 'N'
 GROUP BY P.CD_PESSOA
```

Gostaria de usar fazer essa soma ai em Laravel

Meu model de registro está assim:

```
class Registro extends Model
{
    //
    public function clientes(){
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Cliente', 'cliente', 'id' );
    }

    public function itens(){
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Item', 'item', 'id' );
    }
}
```

No meu controller está assim:

```
public function listRegistro(){

        $registro = Registro::with([ 'clientes', 'itens'] )
                                    ->select( DB::raw('sum( vl_preco ) as valor') )
                                    ->where( 'sn_pago', 'N' )
                                    ->groupBy('cliente')
                                    ->paginate(10);

        $cliente = Cliente::all();
        $item    = Item::all();

        return response()->json( $registro );


    }
```

Mas está retornando assim:

```
    {
  "total": 1,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "valor": "10.00",
      "clientes": null,
      "itens": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Os clientes e os itens nulos

Se eu tentar assim:

```
$registro =  Registro::with(['clientes', 'itens'])
                        ->join( 'clientes', 'registros.cliente','=','clientes.id' )
                        ->join( 'item', 'registros.item','=','item.id' )
                        ->get();
```

Os dados vêm (do cliente e dos itens), mas daí eu não sei como fazer o sum com groupBy

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cliente": 1,
    "item": 1,
    "vl_preco": "10.00",
    "sn_pago": "N",
    "qt_compra": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-11-23 20:16:17",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-23 20:16:17",
    "nm_cliente": "Carlos Bruno",
    "nr_cracha": "4142",
    "empresa": 2,
    "nr_cep": "69084100",
    "nr_casa": "22",
    "ds_complemento": "Casa",
    "dt_cadastro": "2017-11-23",
    "email": "cbcarlos07@gmail.com",
    "senha": "$2y$10$uhsh2MjlYNZcjqiiQb.JBO3d3jD1KX8PUnQWLzB8qgx0sCnKuKidi",
    "sn_senha_atual": "N",
    "ds_item": "Prato Feito",
    "vl_item": "10.00",
    "clientes": {
      "id": 1,
      "nm_cliente": "Carlos Bruno",
      "nr_cracha": "4142",
      "empresa": 2,
      "nr_cep": "69084100",
      "nr_casa": "22",
      "ds_complemento": "Casa",
      "dt_cadastro": "2017-11-23",
      "email": "cbcarlos07@gmail.com",
      "senha": "$2y$10$uhsh2MjlYNZcjqiiQb.JBO3d3jD1KX8PUnQWLzB8qgx0sCnKuKidi",
      "sn_senha_atual": "N",
      "created_at": "2017-11-23 20:17:09",
      "updated_at": "2017-11-23 20:17:09"
    },
    "itens": {
      "id": 1,
      "ds_item": "Prato Feito",
      "vl_item": "10.00",
      "created_at": "2017-11-23 20:16:17",
      "updated_at": "2017-11-23 20:16:17"
    }
  }
]
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: precisa ser com paginação ?

Comment: Deu certo?.....

Comment: Seria legal como paginação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque os valores de Cliente e Item estão vindo nulos, porque, no Select feito não tem os campos para que o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) faça a relação e carrega os valores, ***como solucionar***?

```
public function listRegistro()
{

    $registro = Registro::with([ 'clientes', 'itens'] )
                    ->select( DB::raw('sum( vl_preco ) as valor, cliente, item') )
                    ->where( 'sn_pago', 'N' )
                    ->groupBy('cliente')
                    ->paginate(10);       

    return response()->json( $registro );

}
```

Solução é colocar no `select` os dois campos da relação que são `cliente` e `item`, sem esses campos o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) não consegue fazer a relação e trazer os dados.

Comment: Muito bom. Deu certo. Obrigado mais uma vez